# Latest sent or received message (facebook style)

Tags: mysql, sql, message

```
SELECT p.*, m.*
FROM  " . DB_PREFIX . "messages AS p, " . DB_PREFIX . "members AS m
WHERE p.member_id2='" . $SESSION->conf['member_id'] . "' AND p.member_id1=m.member_id
ORDER BY p.senddate DESC
```

I'm trying to set up an inbox for all users within my social networking website. I'd like to have it setup exactly like Facebook where you would see just one line per conversation with each user. So you would just see the latest received or sent message to that user.

The code above is what I currently have but it's just showing me all received messages. How do I set up a query to find the latest sent or received message (only one line per user)?

member_id1 is the sender
member_id2 is the receiver

Here is a screengrab of my table
https://i.stack.imgur.com/HNV8I.png

Comment: Can you post your expected results using your example table?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT p.*, m.*
FROM  " . DB_PREFIX . "messages AS p, " . DB_PREFIX . "members AS m
WHERE p.member_id2='" . $SESSION->conf['member_id'] . "' AND p.member_id1=m.member_id
ORDER BY p.senddate DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: This just gives me the latest received message from any user. I need the latest sent or received messages between the current user and any user he/she has contacted.

Take a look at your facebook messages inbox. That may give you a better understanding of what I'm looking for.